Reading Data in Python using pandas
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
Loading data from a CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('D:/Projects/FLGRU_Model/FLDataset/01-12/DrDoS_LDAP.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(data)
Performing data analysis
df.head()  # Display the first few rows
df.describe()  # Statistical summary of the data

What could be the problem with the following code,? its not reading the data
I was reading the data and te code is giving the following errors
 DtypeWarning: Columns (85) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  data = pd.read_csv('D:/Projects/FLGRU_Model/FLDataset/01-12/DrDoS_LDAP.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):


The error message seems pretty clear "Columns (85) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False."  Follow the suggested fix.

data = pd.read_csv('D:/Projects/FLGRU_Model/FLDataset/01-12/DrDoS_LDAP.csv') df = pd.read_csv(data) can you just change data to df and delete the second line? If the problem still persists then it's an issue with your 85th column in the dataset having mixed types of data, so set an option to convert all data to another type df = pd.read_csv('D:/Projects/FLGRU_Model/FLDataset/01-12/DrDoS_LDAP.csv', dtype=float) will convert all columns to float Or pass a dictionary of 'column': datatype for every column,

You show a warnng (which I've never seen before) but it isn't clear what the error is.  Is it in the first read_csv or the second extranious one?  What's the purpose of the second?  What's the csv like? Size, rows and columns?  What do they contain?  I believe pandas is pretty good at deducing column dtypes, though mixed ones require object dtype and more memory.

You are reading csv file two times. It should not be done.
Try reading the csv file one time.
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

df = pd.read_csv('<FilePath>')
df.head()  # Display the first few rows
df.describe()  # Statistical summary of the data


while reading data from csv files, data types like int and str are treated as objects.
Check with df.dtypes
Declare the columns data type explicitly and add separator (separator is optional)
Example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': (['1'] * 100000 + ['X'] * 100000 +
                     ['1'] * 100000),
               'b': ['b'] * 300000})  

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
Here, Columns (0) have mixed types. Declaring the data type column indexed 0
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',' , dtype={'a': str})
